# Vaadin Textarea auto height

Tags: java, textarea, vaadin, css

In Vaadin, is it possible to somehow render a textarea that automatically adjusts its height to the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [ExpandingTextArea](http://vaadin.com/addon/expandingtextarea) is an add-on you are looking for. It adjusts the height automatically when you type text into it.